# MQTT - Use Paho in Python to loop a function until a message is received

Tags: python, mqtt

I would like to create a for loop which does some things and then waits until a certain message is sent to a certain MQTT topic before it completes each iteration, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

The code would be something like this:

```
for i in list:
   #do something
   while True:
      if message received on topic x:
         break
```

Any ideas as to how I could go about this?

Comment: What have you tried? The paho [rpc demo](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/client_rpc_math.py#L102) should provide a good starting point (it shows a loop waiting on a message).

Comment: @Brits I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work when the loop is inside a function (which is the case in my code), as the on_message callback is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); its very difficult to comment on code we cannot see.